# What does these $\Delta \Delta G$ numbers signify?

Tags: thermodynamics, biophysics

I was reading a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mikael_Kubista/publication/12969838_Sequence_motifs_and_free_energies_of_selected_natural_and_non-natural_nucleosome_positioning_DNA_sequences/links/0912f511140f11590c000000.pdf) and came across this table showing  $ \Delta \Delta G$ numbers of different nucleotide sequences in DNA/RNA. I know that $\Delta G$ is free energy and $ \Delta \Delta G$ is relative free energy with respect to L. variegatus 5 S RNA gene. What does this numbers signify actually?

[image]

Comment: Can you please link the paper. It is important to have the context of the measurement.

Comment: These are likely binding energies relative to a known interaction. Without seeing the paper, it's impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very basically, what they've done in the paper was incubate different DNA sequences with histone octamers which were then separated on a gel. From this they could measure the ratio between nucleosomal and free DNA, which represents an equilibrium constant. This can then be expressed as a change in free energy ($\Delta G=-RTln(K)$), which is what the table shows. A lower (more negative) free energy change corresponds to a higher equilibrium constant which represents a greater proportion of DNA bound to histones. In other words, the free energy change quantifies the propensity of these different DNA sequences to form nucleosomes.